# Raspberry PI B schematics and hw drawings

Tags: hardware

I was digging in my stuff, and found a bunch of RPis. From what I can tell, they are pretty old - circa 2011,2012 Raspberry Pi B. Visual identifiers are:

- RCA and 3.5mm audio jacks are near the GPIO pins
- CPU is SK Hynix
- Sticker on the back says e2213rs2v13b1.0

I can't find schematics or mechanical drawings for this model. I figure they're old enough, that I can use them to experiment on the hardware - have them resoldered for a project I have in mind, but I could use a reference point.

Update:

First of all, thank you everyone for the help thus far. However, since I still haven't found the information I seek, I am adding additional info.

I am reasonably certain, that the model is **Raspberry R1.0 model B** so the question is not regarding how to identify the board.

Documentation for this model is NOT available at

- https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/
- https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings

Comment: Have you tried searching for raspberry pi wiki?  Identifying the model should be a trivial exercise.

Comment: @Joan, Thank you! I'm not after the model. I'm already 100% certain it's the Raspberry Pi 1 Model B (not B+) I'm looking for the schematics? PCB layout and hardware drawings.

Comment: Perhaps they have not been published.  Check at https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/ and https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings

Comment: @joan Don't see them on either page.

Comment: There aren't complete schematics publicly available for any model of Pi...they're proprietary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Schematics and Mechanical Drawings](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics)
of most models are available.

The Pi Model B did have a reasonably "complete" 5 page schematic (Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf), but does not seem to be included.

Comment: I think the "not included" info is what I am seeking. I've looked through the rest of the documents already, but it does not seem to match the boards I have on hand.

Comment: I don't know why you would want the schematic. The vast bulk of users don't. I am interested because I used to design my own computers but everything you need to know to use the Pi is readily available. If you have a specific question ask.

Comment: Well, I read that RPi has a PCIe bus, I've found instructions, videos et al, but not for the model I have.

Comment: The Pi DOES NOT have a PCIe bus. If interested a search for Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf found the schematic.

Comment: Darn, you are right... looks like it only appeared in later versions of RPi

Answer (score 1):

The information you seek should be at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html

To determine the version of a pi is simple if you have a running linux on it; see https://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory

Note that, although some information is available, it may not be complete. See  https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=55777 for an explanation.